# Improving a nested loop for efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I'm working on a project on analysis of PSL files. The program overall looks at readpairs and identifies circular molecules. I've got the program working, but the fact that my operations are nested makes it very inefficient taking longer than 10 minutes to read through the whole PSL file instead of ~15seconds like it should.

The relative code is:

```
def readPSLpairs(self):

    posread = []
    negread = []
    result = {}
    for psl in self.readPSL():
        parsed = psl.split()
        strand = parsed[9][-1]
        if strand == '1':
            posread.append(parsed)
        elif strand == '2':
            negread.append(parsed)

    for read in posread:
        posname = read[9][:-2]
        poscontig = read[13]
        for read in negread:
            negname = read[9][:-2]
            negcontig = read[13]
            if posname == negname and poscontig == negcontig:
                try:
                    result[poscontig] += 1
                    break
                except:
                    result[poscontig] = 1
                    break
    print(result)
```

I have attempted changing the overall operation to instead append the values to lists and attempt to then match posname = negname and poscontig = negcontig, but it proves to be much harder than I thought it would, so I'm stuck on trying to improve the functionality of it all.

Comment: maintain a set of pairs `(negname, negcontig)` that you build up during the initial loop, and then you can just do a quick lookup instead of iterating `negread`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by maintaining a set of pairs?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out the set - https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: are any of the `pos` or `neg` values repeated? Or all they all unique?

Comment: ooh @AdamSmith has a good point - sets won't work if there are dupes.  But then you could maintain a dict where the key is the pair, and the value is the count.  Use a defaultdict

Comment: yes there are repeated values. pos/neg contigs can and are repeated multiple times. As far as I know the names are unique.

Comment: consider parsing once with `defaultdict`, then checking against the dict for matches. That changes your solution to `O(n)`

Comment: It seems as though you're building lists (posread & negread) as you go. If you know of an upper bound on their size, maybe you could pre-allocate them (i.e. posread = [None for x in range(upperbound)]), that might save time used for reallocating your lists as they grow. You would just need to maintain an end-of-active list counter.

Comment: user1245262 I don't know the upper bound on their size.
@AdamSmith if im understanding you correctly, I should defaultdict posname/poscontig and check against it with the negname/negcontig values?

Comment: @user1245262 that's not really going to help much. Fixed-length arrays aren't hardly used in Python because the increased in efficiency is negligible and not worth the fact that it's harder to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections

all_dict = {"pos": collections.defaultdict(int),
            "neg": collections.defaultdict(int)}

result = {}

for psl in self.readPSL():
    parsed = pls.split()
    strand = "pos" if parsed[9][-1]=='1' else "neg"
    name, contig = parsed[9][:-2], parsed[13]
    all_dict[strand][(name,contig)] += 1
# pre-process all the psl's into all_dict['pos'] or all_dict['neg']
#   this is basically just a `collections.Counter` of what you're doing already!

for info, posqty in all_dict['pos'].items():
    negqty = all_dict['neg'][info]  # (defaults to zero)
    result[info] = qty * other_qty
# process all the 'pos' psl's. For every match with a 'neg', set
#   result[(name, contig)] to the total (posqty * negqty)
```

Note that this throws away the whole parsed psl value, keeping only the `name` and `contig` slices.